# How to apply cutoff in path integral?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, path-integral, regularization

I am working on harmonic oscillator for quantum fluctuations (apart from clasical part), path may written as
$$
S_q=\int_0^Tdt[(\partial_tq)^2+w^2q^2]
$$
This may written as 
$$
S_q=\int dt(q\Delta q)
$$
for $\Delta=-\partial_u^2+w^2$ after Wick rotation. 
Boundary conditions must hold $q(0)=0;q(T)=0$,then I may use the Fourier transform to define eigenvectors.
$$
\psi_n(t)=A^\frac{1}{2}sin(\frac{n\pi t}{T})
$$
And the eigenvector is
$$
\lambda_n=\frac{n^2\pi^2+w^2T^2}{T^2}
$$
Then I may write 
$$\tag{1}det\Delta \approx \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2\pi^2+w^2T^2}{T^2}
$$
But eq(1) is obviously divergent for $n \to \infty$

How am I suppose to manage that? Should I apply any cutoff, if yes how?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you want to do. Do you have reason to believe the functional determinant of $\Delta$ should be finite? That is, what is there to "manage" here, exactly?

Comment: I need to evaluate the Kernel $K(q_f,T; q_i,0)=\int [dq] exp(S_q)$ I suppose this should give me finite solution. Classical part of this Kernel is finite and I'm wondering this should also be finite or regularize somehow.